# select adjacent element's child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<div class="srch-sb-results"> stuff here </div>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td colspan='3'>
         <div style="border:1px solid silver"></div>
       </td>
     </tr>
<table>
```

I need to select the div that is rendering the silver border How do I select the div in jquery and hide it? As well as the table cell with colspan.

Comment: What do you mean? Select it relative to which element?

Comment: Can you give more context? When are you trying to hide the table column / div? Is the html predefined or can you change it?

Comment: select it based on $(.'srch-sb-results').next().find('div')..... something like this.. I have no control over html...

Comment: @SarikaThapaliya no control means ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.srch-sb-results').next('table').find('td[colspan="3"]').hide();
```

that should do it. Including the OP's original request to hide the td having a colspan=3

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('table div').each(function() {//selects all divs inside table

    var bColor = $(this).css('border-color');//checks each element's border-color
    if( bColor === 'silver') {
       $(this).hide();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the html you could use an adjacent siblings CSS selector to select the first div inside the first table cell of the first table row like this:

```
$('.srch-sb-results + table > tr:first > td:first > div:first').hide();
```

Easier would be to change the HTML and set an ID on the div and select that directly.

Answer (score 0):

if this div is the only:

```
$('td[colspan="3"] > div').hide();
```

or more strict to CSS should be something like this:

```
$('td[colspan="3"] div').each(function(){
  if ($(this).css('border')) $(this).hide();
});
```